# Why all values are quoted when I use cbind with an object that comes from a gsub function?

Tags: r

I have the following matrix:

```
head(perc)
band     perc_SC   perc_SH   perc_WH perc_Tot
1    1 0.009104271 0.6651940 0.3257017        1
2    2 0.008963893 0.6289139 0.3621222        1
3    3 0.008837757 0.6186107 0.3725515        1
4    4 0.008495426 0.6395086 0.3519959        1
5    5 0.008152846 0.6563294 0.3355178        1
6    6 0.007516888 0.6615440 0.3309391        1
```

I need to take the name of the file and inserted as a column, so I do this

```
key <- names(B)
country <- gsub("\\_.*","",key)
```

then,

```
perc1 <- cbind(country,perc)
```

and got this:

```
> head(perc1)
country       band perc_SC perc_SH perc_WH perc_Tot
"Argentina"   "1"  "0.009" "0.665" "0.325" "1"
```

How can avoid the quotes in perc1 values?

Comment: what is `B` in the code?  If `perc` is a `matrix`, then `matrix` can hold only a single class.  It gets converted to `character` when there is one character element added.  Try with `cbind(country, as.data.frame(perc))`

Comment: Because a matrix can't hold several types. When you `cbind` a character vector with a numeric matrix, it converts all the values to the highest type (which is character)

Comment: B is a raster .tif file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?cbind`:

> The type of a matrix result determined from the highest type of any of the inputs in the hierarchy raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list .

Therefore, when you combine `numeric` and `character` columns with `cbind`, it will convert all input to `character`, as this is the highest type.